# loop through Nested Array and finding index number

Tags: python, arrays

```
array = [     
              ["Bitcoin", "Bitcoin"],
              ["Ethereum", "Bitcoin"],
              ["XRP", "Bitcoin"],
        ]
```

I want to search for the keyword "Ethereum" and I want to output the index of the place in the array (2).
Now it is putting out the place in the array of the nested array (0).

```
for counter in subreddits:
  #subredditIndex = counter.index("Ethereum")
    try:
        print(counter.index("XRP"))
        # print(counter[0])
        # print(type(counter[0]))
    except:
        print("No string found")
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: It's not an array, it's a nested list. And, agreed, this is not a Java question

Comment: Using a bare expect statement is poor design.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep track of the outer index.

```py
etherium_index = None
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    if myList[i][0] == 'Etherium':
        etherium_index = i
```

Comment: You can't `return` without a function, and the OP didn't include one

Comment: Changed it to fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Ethereum"
for ind, element in enumerate(array):
    if s in element:
        print(ind)
```